# Error en Servicio de Windows cuando actualizo una dll firmada

Tags: c#, windows, servicio, upload

Tengo un servicio Windows que el ejecutable llama a una dll (que llamaré NombreMiDll.dll) con la versión 0.6.7.3, por ejemplo.

Todo funciona correctamente hasta que actualizo esa dll a la versión 0.6.7.4.  Que al reiniciar el servicio, para que coja la nueva versión del la dll me devuelve el siguiente error:

> No se puede iniciar el servicio. System.IO.FileLoadException: No se
>   puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'NombreMiDll, Version=0.6.7.3,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=59f75f9107acaf71' ni una de sus
>   dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide
>   con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Nombre de archivo: 'NombreMiDll, Version=0.6.7.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=59f75f9107acaf71'    en
>   CallerCofnaService.Service1.OnStart(String[] args)    en
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state)
>
> AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado. Para
>   habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca
>   el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) como 1. Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada
>   registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado. Para desactivar esta
>   característica, elimine el valor de Registro
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

¿Alguien sabría decirme como puedo evitar este error, y poder actualizar la dll sin ningún problema?
La dll se actualiza automáticamente y sola, verificando cada X tiempo si hay una nueva versión.  Si la hay la descarga y reinicia el servicio.

La dll la he compilado yo, y está escrita en c# Framework 2.0 (requisitos del proyecto).

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: el problema, si no me equivoco, es que en tu servicio haces referencia a una dll. Cuando la actualizas, deberías actualizar esa referencia puesto que se queda apuntando a la dll anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero muchas gracias por vuestra colaboración.
El problema (y la posterior solución) la he encontrado en mantener fijo el valor 
AssemblyVersion y modificar únicamente el AssemblyFileVersion.

De esta forma, aunque la dll esté firmada, al llamarla utilza el AssemblyVersion, pero el sistema de actualización utiliza el AssemblyFileVersion.

Muchas gracias a todo el foro, y muchas gracias por las respuestas.  La utilización del [assemblyBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/twy1dw1e(v=vs.110).aspx) como sugiere [Sergio Parra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1898/sergio-parra-guerra) me ha dado ideas de optimizar el proceso de compilación.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que compilar todo el servicio y publicarlo en la maquina nuevamente. El servicio que tienes espera la dll `NombreMiDll.dll` con la version `0.6.7.3` pero le estas pasando la version `0.6.7.4` por lo que no podrá encontrar la dll con la que fue compilada inicialmente.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, aunque he leído que no es recomendable cambiar de DLL en tiempo de ejecución:

```
try
        {
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments.ToString());
            var dlls = info.GetFiles(@"*.dll").ToList();
            foreach (FileInfo item in dlls)
            {
                var loadedDll = Assembly.LoadFile(item.FullName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Respuesta obtenida de: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/503f5448-00cc-48d4-8360-40ec40697acb/actualizar-dll-dinamicamente?forum=vcses

Answer (score 0):

puedes configurar el elemento [assemblyBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/twy1dw1e(v=vs.110).aspx) en tu archivo de configuración para poder usar una versión u otra de un ensamblado aplicando `bindingRedirect`.
Un ejemplo puede ser

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
            <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"
                      href="http://www.litwareinc.com/myAssembly.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```